# Crash when trying to set delegate - FBLoginView

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, fbloginview

I'm using facebook login in my app. It works well.
But I'm getting a crash with no error message when I reopen the app after quit the app by double tap the home button. Xcode points to the class **`FBLoginView.m`** and method **`- (void)informDelegate:(BOOL)userOnly`**
The delegate is nil inside the method. But the method calls from **`SetDelegate`** method where the delegate is not null
Any idea about the reason for the issue.
                                                                                                     Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: set the delegate where needed (in button click action) not in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear or in Appdelegate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the delegate connection from storyboard. And removed the code that used to set the delegate from viewdidLoad.
I parsed the subviews of the fbLoginView and set action to the UIButtoon object. And set delegate inside the UIButton action method.
Now it working well.